# difference between [] and {{}} bindings in Angular

Tags: angular

For example i can use {{}} bindings:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
```

or [] property bindings:

```
<img [src]="imgsrc">
```

So what’s the differences between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with string interpolation '{{}}' you can bind expressions that only can be converted into a strings.
But if you want to bind other type you can use property binding '[]'
example:

you hava a variable that contains a boolean value:

```
isLoading = false;
```

so, if you use string interpolation, you actually convert false to 'false'

```
<p>{{isLoading}}</p>
```

That convert the value of isLoading to a string 'false' to rederize on the DOM.

But if you bind with property binding you will be pass the boolean value, and not will be converted to string

```
<button [disabled]="isLoading"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `[ ]` and `{{ }}` can be summarised in that one is used for property binding and the other as a means for string interpolation.

To quote for the `[ ]`:

> To bind to an element's property, enclose it in square brackets, `[ ]`, which identifies the property as a target property.

This the use case for `[ ]` is for property binding, when we want to set the value of attribute of an HTML element. This is most commonly used for binding of HTML attributes, like the `[src]` attribute in the `img` tag. The other use case is to pass values from a parent component to a child component.
The full explanation of this mechanism can be found in the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/property-binding#binding-to-a-property).

For example, consider the following HTML:

```html
<button [disabled]="true">Foo</button>
```

Here the button is disabled since we are setting the HTML attribute `disabled` to `true`.

Regarding the `{{ }}`:

> Interpolation refers to embedding expressions into marked up text. By default, interpolation uses the double curly braces `{{` and `}}` as delimiters.

This is used when we want to display a value in our HTML that is given by the value of a variable from our typescript. It simply replaces the value of the typescript variable in the HTML. The full explanation of this can be found in the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/interpolation).

For example, consider the following TS and HTML:

```html
<button>{{ foo }}</button>
```

```js
@Component(...)
export class CustomComponent {
  foo = 'Click me!';
}
```

Angular would render a button with the text `'Click me!'` after change detection had run:

```html
<button>Click me!</button>
```

If we where to change the value of the `foo` variable, it would also update the value displayed in the button.

Comment: thanks, very clear and precise definition!